# Prove that $ BP = B $ where $ P $ is the projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For an $ m \times n $ matrix $ A $, let $ P = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T $. For a column vector $ v $, let $ B = v(v^Tv)^{-1}v^T $. Prove that $ BP = B $.
I was able to do this problem if $ v $ was replaced by an invertible matrix $ C $ because $ C(C^TC)^{-1}C^T = CC^{-1}(C^T)^{-1}C^T = I $, but I'm not sure how to do this for column vectors.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not $BP=B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let consider the projection matrix $(I-P)$ onto the othogonal complement, then we have that

$$B(I-P)=0 \implies B-BP=0 \implies BP=B$$

which is $\neq P$ in general.